# TERADATA : Joining Tables

Tags: sql, calendar, inner-join, teradata

I have a table which I have generated where the information is rolled up to aggregates per day
I have a second table which can be considered a calendar table which allows me when joining the tables to get the week number of the aggregates

The date in the tables are all integers e.g. 20130501 (YYYYMMDD)

When i create the SQL below (generalized) it works fine but now i want to schedule this script to run once a week to get the previous week and am getting an error

**Script works fine**

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_1 as sample
    INNER JOIN TABLE_2 as calendar
    ON sample.day = calendar.day
    WHERE sample.day >= 20130501
    AND sample.day <= 20130507
```

**Script Fails**

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_1 as sample
    INNER JOIN TABLE_2 as calendar
    ON sample.day = calendar.day
    -- >= Previous Monday Last week
    WHERE sample.day >= CAST(CAST(((DATE-DAYOFWEEK(DATE)-5) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')) AS CHAR(8)) AS INT)
   --  <= Previous Sunday Last week
    AND   sample.day <= CAST(CAST(((DATE-DAYOFWEEK(DATE)+ 1) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')) AS CHAR(8)) AS INT)
```

The Error message I'm getting on the second script is

*Teradata ODBC Teradata Driver Syntax Error: expected something between ')' and '-'*

Thank you all for your time
It has been troubling me for a few days now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAYOFWEEK is not a built-in Teradata function.
There's a DAYOFWEEK ODBC function but you have to switch on a flag in the ODBC driver to be able to use it.

Depending on your release there might be a UDF like TD_DAY_OF_WEEK or you write your own SQL-UDF. Otherwise try this:

```
BETWEEN CAST(CURRENT_DATE - ((CURRENT_DATE - DATE '0001-01-07') MOD 7) - 6 AS INT) + 19000000
    AND CAST(CURRENT_DATE - ((CURRENT_DATE - DATE '0001-01-07') MOD 7)     AS INT) + 19000000
```